# Is the metric tensor a differential form and can we integrate it?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms, multiple-integral

I wasn't sure if to ask this question on math SE or physics SE, but I figured it was entirely mathematical in nature with only applications in physics.

That being said, the "metric tensor" $g$ is really a section of the bilinear form bundle $T^*M\otimes T^*M\xrightarrow{\pi}M$ such that $g_p:T_pM\times T_pM\to\mathbb{R}$ is symmetric and non-degenerate for all $p\in M$.

On the other hand, a "differential $2$-form" $\omega$ is also really a section, and $\omega_p$ also eats two vectors and outputs a scalar. Furthermore, we can integrate this
$$\iint_\Omega \omega$$
over a region $\Omega\subseteq M$ of dimension $2$.

**My question is:** Is the metric tensor also a *differential* form and can we integrate it over a region of a pseudo-Riemannian manifold?

$$\iint_\Omega g$$

Would the result be anything physical or meaningful?

Comment: Differential forms are _alternating_ forms; metric tensors are not. If we approximate a manifold as a union of non-overlapping parallelepipeds, then each parallelepiped is described by $n$ tangent vectors (half of its edges). Only an alternating form (the value of a differential form at each point) can take those vectors as input and return the volume of the parallelepiped they describe. The value of a metric tensor at a point is used to compute the inner product of two vectors at that point. With no alternating form, there's no way to assign size/measure to the approximating parallelepipeds.

Comment: @JoeMac Okay that makes sense if only alternating forms can be integrated, but what about the area of a parallelepiped using the cross product $|u\times v|=u\cdot v\,\tan\,\theta=g(u,v)\,\tan\,\theta$? (Where the tangent is calculated from $g$)

Comment: Don't get me wrong: there are important relations between a manifold's metric tensor and its [volume form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_form). But getting some analogue of Riemann integration on a manifold requires an alternating form, which the metric tensor is not.

Comment: That formula doesn't work. Suppose $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ are anchored at the same point, are both nonzero, and are perpendicular. Then the parallelogram they define has nonzero area, but your use of $\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{v}$ would suggest otherwise. That's why it's safer to stick with $|\mathbf{u}\times\mathbf{v}| = |\mathbf{u}||\mathbf{v}|\sin\theta$.

Comment: @JoeMac Yeah $u\cdot v$ would be zero but $\tan\,\theta$ would be undefined (tending toward infinity as $\theta\to\pi/2^-$) which would allow any other angle and 90° as a limiting case. Though I agree that integration requires an alternating form.